# Connecting to SQL Server 2012 on IIS8 with PHP_SQLSRV

Tags: php, asp.net, sql

This is a project, so doesn't require extreme levels of caution/security - I'd like to get it working and then improve it from there.

### How can I get PHP to connect successfully to SQL Server 2012

What I have done successfully:

- Enabled mixed authentication on SQL Server 2012
- Established an account using SQL authentication
- Set up FastCGI on IIS and configured PHP.ini
- .PHP scripts in the web root execute successfully
- I can use SSMS to connect locally to the SQL database using the credentials (SQL Authentication) I created

The problem:

- I cannot use a PHP script to successfully connect to the local SQL database.

What I have considered, but do not understand well enough to diagnose:

- That the HTTP connections to IIS are impersonating IUSR, which has permissions to read/execute PHP scripts in the web root, but may not have permission to connect to the server?
- That for some reason my connection dialogue is simply ineffective

Here is my connect script:

```
$serverName = 'localhost';
$connectionInfo = array( 'Database'=>'DATABASE',
                       'Encrypt'=>'1', 'UID'=>'user', 'PWD'=>'password' );

$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $connection == false )
{
  echo "No connection was established.\n";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Here are my errors (unfortunately PHP does not pretty print them):

```
No connection was established. Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001
        [code] => -2146893019
        [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001
        [code] => -2146893019
        [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Client unable to establish connection
    )
)
```

I also tried using process monitor to check w3wp.exe when I load the script through a browser - I don't know how I would paste the information from that, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with its output.

Comment: My server name and database name contain hyphens and are all caps, such as "ABC-DEFGHI"

Comment: Also it uses a self-signed certificate and only allows SSL connections for IIS (so, HTTP/SSL, so only HTTPS)

Comment: "the HTTP connections to IIS are impersonating IUSR" - if you're not using Windows Authentication that won't matter.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is straight-forward: the SSL certificate you're using on your SQL Server is self-signed and so is not trusted by the consumer.

Possible solutions include:

- Disable SSL/TLS on your SQL Server
- Use a non-secured connection to your SQL Server
- Add the self-signed certificate to the consumer's trusted certificate store
- Get a trusted certificate from a public CA (Namecheap do them for less then $20)